# Validating user entry by referencing to an enum in Java

Tags: java, validation, enums

I have made the following `enum` `Class`.

```
public enum Option {
    ONE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5);

    private int option;

    private Option(int option) {
        this.option = option;
    }

    public int getOption() {
        return option;
    }
}
```

Now user is asked to input a value 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5

```
int value =  input.nextInt();
```

Can I check if the user has made a valid entry using the `enum`?

Comment: `Arrays.stream(Option.values()).anyMatch(o -> o.getOption() == value)`